# Excel VBA Call Web, ignore Run Type Error 13 "Mismatch Type" Message Box when current value is cleared

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, stock

Sub Get_Web_Data(ByVal Target As Range)
' https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/TSLA

Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim website As String
Dim price As Variant

' Website to go to.
website = "https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/" & Target.Value & "/research-ratings"

' Create the object that will make the webpage request.
Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

' Where to go and how to go there - probably don't need to change this.
request.Open "GET", website, False

' Get fresh data.
request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"

' Send the request for the webpage.
request.send

' Get the webpage response data into a variable.
response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)

' Put the webpage into an html object to make data references easier.
html.body.innerHTML = response

' Get the price from the specified element on the page.
price = html.getElementsByClassName("cr_data rr_stockprice module").Item(0).innerText

' Output the price into a message box.

If Target.Column = 4 Then
Range("O" & Target.Row).Value = price
Else
Range("AE" & Target.Row).Value = price
End If

End Sub

Sheet 1

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D2,D14,D26,D38,D50,T2,T14,T26,T38,T50")) Is Nothing Then
    
   
   Call Get_Web_Data(Target)

End If
```

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub

Comment: I keep getting an error when i clear the referenced cells that call the web for stock info. It tells me an error on (website = "https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/" & Target.Value & "/research-ratings") in the module 1. How can i stop the Run Time Error 13 message from showing when when clearing the data in the cell.

Comment: you haven't assigned a value or declared `target` Is this inside an event? Please include the signature (the start of the sub). It is likely you need to wrap that line (maybe something else) with switching EnableEvents to False then later back to True

Comment: Oh sorry, just updated the starting sub

Comment: Nvm found the answer, just put " on error resume next"  after (Sub Get_Web_Data(ByVal Target As Range)